# Boot correct initrd in UEFI with multiple ESP partitions

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

I have a computer which boots into Debian using UEFI and the kernel efi-stub. The ESP partition is on the first disk (`/dev/sda1`)

To learn about UEFI booting and the details of linux booting I've created a USB linux image. I've created a vfat partition on the USB with esp flag with the following layout:

```
EFI\
 |
 + BOOT\
    |
    + BOOTX64.EFI
    |
    + STARTUP.NSH
    |
    + INITRD.IMG
    |
    + VMLINUZ.EFI
```

The contents of startup.nsh is:

```
vmlinuz.efi ro root=UUID=<uuid> rootfstype=ext3 add_efi_memmap initrd=initrd.img console=tty0
```

The problem is when I perform a one-shot boot from the USB stick the `initrd=initrd.img` is loading the file from the Debian installation on `/dev/sda1` instead of the one from the USB stick. I'm speculating that it's because the Debian disk shows up as `fs0:` while the USB stick shows up as `fs1:` in the UEFI shell.

My question is how can ensure the uefi shell/kernel loads `vmlinuz` and `initrd` only from the same device that it read the startup.nsh from?